# Axios + Promise add parameter to then method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios, es6-promise

I made a axios post call in a Promise, and **I want to get the ajax respone in the Promise then method**.

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post('/api/products/modify', product).
        then(r => {
          if(r && r.data && r.data.result) {
            return {productId: r.data.result};
          } else {
            console.error("actions addproduct error occours during modifying the product! Error: " + r.data.error);
            reject(r.data.error);
          }
        }).
        catch((error) => {
          console.error("actions addproduct; error occours during adding the product! Error: " + error);
          reject(error);
        });
      }
    });
```

And when I call `p.then();` I want to get the `{productId: r.data.result}` object.

I tried this:

```
p.then(r => {
          console.debug("response: " + r);
        });
```

But does not work. However the ajax call is reaching the server, so the promise works, but I can not add the result to the then method.

Thx for the response in advance!

Comment: taking apart missing " from console.debug(response: " + r), what exactly returns console.debug?

Comment: nothing... that's the weird part. Btw thx, i edited the question

Comment: how you are testing? in which environment? browser?

Comment: Chromium: Version 65.0.3325.181, I packing with webpack.. it should work

Comment: Is verbose level checked for logging? have you tried testing the call with postman?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! The `return` you had was fine, but you should simply `throw` your errors and then use the promise that `then()` already creates for you:

```
return axios.post('/api/products/modify', product).then(r => {
    if (r && r.data && r.data.result) {
        return {productId: r.data.result};
    } else {
        console.error("actions addproduct error occours during modifying the product! Error: " + r.data.error);
        throw r.data.error;
    }
}, error => {
      console.error("actions addproduct; error occours during adding the product! Error: " + error);
      throw error;
});
```

Or without the logs:

```
return axios.post('/api/products/modify', product).then(r => {
    if (r.data.result) {
        return {productId: r.data.result};
    } else {
        throw r.data.error;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm going to give it a chance.

Comment: My challenge has been when axios does not pass up the "then" chain value properly to the caller's then() handler (added on the returned promise object.  Instead it always returns the entire raw "response" which seems like a bug or the additional handler is not defined due to a race condition?  The above example only does everything inline.

Comment: @justdan23 You might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with an [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Use resolve() instead of return.

```
if(r && r.data && r.data.result) {
  resolve({productId: r.data.result});
}
```

Comment: There is no need for `new Promise` in the first place as `axios.post` already returns a promise.